# Woocommerce Rest API issue with stock quantity

Tags: php, woocommerce

I create Woocommerce products in my ionic app. I would like also to push the stock quantity when I create the product. However, the stock always is with NULL stored in my MYSQL DB. Here is the JSON feed

```
{
  "product": {
    "title": "test stock",
    "stock_quantity": "35",
    "images": [],
    "post_author": 88,
    "type": "simple",
    "categories": []
  }
}:
```

And here the piece of code from the app

```
  var productInfo = {
    title: this.productName,
    regular_price: this.productPrice,
    sale_price: this.productDiscount,
    stock_quantity: this.productStock,
    description: this.productDesc,
    images: new Array<any>(),
    post_author: this.userService.id,
    type: this.productType,
    categories: new Array<any>()
  };
```

I tried different tags for stock_quantity like only "stock" and tried to push the variable with "" and without it. But I'm facing still the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON syntax is correct. Also, you are passing the correct parameter for the stock as `stock_quantity` and as I reviewed your JSON request you have not passed the `manage_stock` parameter as true by default that considers as false. so, you need to pass that parameter also.

You can try the following code.

```
{
 "product": {
 "title": "test stock",
 "stock_quantity": "35",
 "manage_stock": true,
 "images": [],
 "post_author": 88,
 "type": "simple",
 "categories": []
 }
}:
```

you can refere the  [WooCommerce REST API Product Properties for create products](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#product-properties)

Comment: I did this as well, but still I get the response null.